# GCC Include Error OpenSSL

Tags: c, gcc, cryptography, openssl, libssl

I'm trying to use openssl crypto lib in my application but i've some issues when I include OpenSSL headers.

First of all i'm tryong to reuse this code :
http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

In my crypto_file I've this code :

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include "global.h"
#include "api_openssl.h"

void init_ctx();

int private_encrypt(byte *plaintext, int plaintex_len, byte *key, byte* iv,byte *cipher)
{
    //TODO
    return 0;
}
int private_decrypt(byte *ciphertext, int ciphertex_len, byte *key, byte* iv,byte *plain)
{
    //TODO
    return 0;
}

void private_init()
{
      ERR_load_crypto_strings();
      OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
      OPENSSL_config(NULL);
}

void private_clean_up()
{
      EVP_cleanup();
      ERR_free_strings();
}
```

and when i wan't to compile thanks to this command:

```
gcc  -std=c99 -Wall -g -c -I inc -DSSL -o obj/api_openssl.o -c src/api_openssl.c
```

I have this result:

```
<command-line>:0:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
```

For your information:

```
 cat /etc/*-release
 ->DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
 DISTRIB_RELEASE=16
 DISTRIB_CODENAME=petra
 DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 16 Petra"
 NAME="Ubuntu"
 VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"
 ID=ubuntu
 ID_LIKE=debian
 PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10"
 VERSION_ID="13.10"
 HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
 SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
 BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

And I've the package libssl-dev of default repository installed

I'm running out of solution.

Thank's for helping me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is coming from the `-DSSL` gcc option. Changing it to `-D_SSL`, or anything else really, prevents the error. I'm not sure, but this leads me to believe that `SSL` is either reserved somewhere or in conflict with something. Maybe someone else can comment on why this is.

That said, where is the `SSL` macro used? Are you able to change it?

Comment: In fact it was just a constant to include one or two libraries, so I have change constant name with a prefix and everything works fine thanks